# Bazel sh_test doesn't find node

Tags: node.js, bazel, bazel-rules

I am trying to run a script which needs `node`. I have node installed in my machine.
I can run `sh_binary` by `bazel run //:sh_bin` and the script runs node just fine:

```
sh_binary(
    name = "sh_bin",
    data = [
    ],
    srcs = [":script.sh"],
)
```

`script.sh`:

```
node -v
```

`bazel run //:sh_bin`:

```
v14.17.6
```

Now I want to convert this to `sh_test`:

```
sh_test(
    name = "sh_bin",
    data = [
    ],
    srcs = [":script.sh"],
)
```

but now `bazel test //:sh_bin` cannot find node:

```
node: command not found
```

I also tried to add `local = True` to the test and still the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bazel tests are run in a more controlled environment than application run via `bazel run`. One of the initial conditions that the *test runner* establishes is the value of `$PATH`: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/test-encyclopedia.html#initial-conditions

If you are working with remote execution, another problem could be that your test is executed on a machine that does not have node installed.

It's always a great idea to strive for a hermetic build that runs and tests independent of the host's state. That means you'd need to make the `node` program available to your binary or test as a *data dep*.

A good alternative is to build on existing work such as https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs.

That being said, your example actually works for me.

```
cd `mktemp -d`
touch WORKSPACE
echo "node -v" > script.sh
chmod +x script.sh
cat <<EOF > BUILD
sh_test(
    name = "sh_bin",
    srcs = [":script.sh"],
)
EOF
bazel test --test_output=all -- //:sh_bin
```

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Analyzed target //:sh_bin (24 packages loaded, 282 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
INFO: From Testing //:sh_bin:
==================== Test output for //:sh_bin:
v17.1.0
================================================================================
Target //:sh_bin up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/sh_bin
INFO: Elapsed time: 6.895s, Critical Path: 0.10s
INFO: 5 processes: 3 internal, 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5 total actions
//:sh_bin                                                                PASSED in 0.0s

Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5 total actions
```